Parsing malformed XML UTC DateTime values in Golang
In my program, I am parsing/decoding XML files and storing values in structs, using the Decoder.Decode() function. The files contain several malformed UTC dates, intended to be parsed as time.Time values and stored in the database.
The two types of dates in the XML content are -

Correctly formatted - "2015-03-12T20:05:18+05:30"
Incorrect formatting - "2020-06-29T11:11:04"

The incorrect dates are missing the timezone offset (that is present in the correctly formatted dates) or the "Z" at the end, indicating 00:00.
During parsing, the decoder fails to parse the malformed dates, and throws an error, complaining about the missing offset.
Before storing the parsed Time values in the database, I am using .format() on them to format it in the layout of 2006-01-02 15:04:05 +0000 (basically storing without the offset). This .format() function also fails, throwing a similar error -
error: parsing time "2020-06-29T11:11:04" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00": cannot parse "" as "Z07:00"

If I could somehow get an exact string representation of these malformed dates, I could append a "Z" at the end, and then parse it, which solves the issue. Here is that code on the playground - https://go.dev/play/p/IbwGgnNtw6P
However, using the in-built String() function does not work, as it either throws the same error or returns a string with an incorrect offset added twice, as described here - Golang time - time zone showing twice
How do I parse the incorrectly formatted dates?

I would suggest to pre-process XML via XSLT transformation to fix the dates to make them conformant with the dateTimeStamp data type. You can use for that a so called Identity Transform pattern in XSLT.

This may be a little blunt but if your input is ISO 8601 formatted like shown, you would need only a string length check to determine the necessity to add a 'Z'. Given of course that a datetime like "2020-06-29T11:11:04" actually is UTC+0 and not some other offset that just got lost. The parser would still "validate" the format, so if you just happen to have some string that has the same length and append a Z, that would still fail.

You need to include a [mcve] in the question, not as linked code somewhere else. When that link expires, this question becomes much less useful to future readers.

How are you parsing the XML? Can't you simply parse the date values as strings instead of dates and then process them afterwards?
